# add title to table when exporting to excel

Tags: javascript, html, excel, html-table

I have this function

```
let button = document.querySelector("#table-export-btn");
    button.addEventListener("click", e => {
    let table = document.querySelector("#myTable");
        TableToExcel.convert(table);
    });
```

I want to also be able to add a title to my table when I export the table but the ways ive tried havent worked so far. I can't just add a title as a row because it affected sorting ability of the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to clone your table and add the head to the clone of your table:

```
let button = document.querySelector("#table-export-btn");

button.addEventListener("click", e => {
  const table = document.querySelector("#myTable");
  let clone = table.cloneNode(true);

  let head = document.createElement('tr');
  // add your stuff here to your head

  clone.prepend(head)

  TableToExcel.convert(clone);
});
```

With this approach, the original table is not going to be changed.